# Rails + Mongoid + Devise : Add a birthday field to the register form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I'm using Rails 3.2.11, mongoid 3.1.2 and devise 2.2.3 and I have an User model with a birtday Date field.

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :birthday, type: Date
    field :email, type: String, default: ""
    field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: ""
    field :remember_created_at, type: Time

    attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :birthday

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :rememberable, :validatable

    validates_presence_of :email, :birthday

    ...
end
```

I added a **birthday** field to the register form as follow:

```
f.input :birthday, :as => :date, :start_year => (Date.current - 5.year).year, :end_year => (Date.current - 120.year).year, :include_blank => true
```

The problem is that when I register I always get the error : Birthday can't be blank.

When I look at the logs I see :

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 13:58:27 +0200
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Cmjq47KqHWzEoytGxH+L5s5zbWrHYDZn221Dq6+wVQQ=", "user"=>{"email"=>"lalala@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",  "birthday(3i)"=>"25", "birthday(2i)"=>"11", "birthday(1i)"=>"1984"}
```

So I don't see why it's not working :(
I've googling this for hours without any chances. I though it could come from mongoid's mass assignement or devise build_ressource but I did not find any solution. Do you already get this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to include another module into your model class:

```
Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! It works like a charm. They should add to the "reasons" : some gems such as devise require it!! http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/rails.html